# PHP: Removing multiple values in foreach

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

Hey guys here is my php:

```
$x = array("one", "two", "three");
foreach ($x as $value)
{
  if ($value != 'one' && $value != 'two')
  {
    echo $value . "<br />";
  }
}
```

This echo's only the word three. I had to use $value != 'one' && $value != 'two' to make this happen and I was wondering if I could consolidate this into something like this:

```
if ($value != 'one, two')
```

That doesn't work so I was wondering if you guys could provide some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!in_array($value, array('one', 'two')))
  echo $value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a switch statement to make it look prettier, but that's as far as you can go.

```
switch ($i) {
    case "one":
    case "two":
    case "three":
        echo $value . '<br/>';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to print or do certain operation when value == 'three'
then only look for value =='three'

```
  foreach ($x as $value) 
 {
      if($value === "three")
      echo $value;
 }
```

also you can take a look at using === operator to compare strings.
since == uses type juggling while === enforces same type (2 strings, 2 int no mixing)
link:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

Skip the foreach altogether:

```
$x=array("one","two","three");
$exclude=array("one","two");

print_r(array_diff($x, $exclude));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($value == 'three')
```

maybe this?